# System JS load multiple dependencies in one call

Tags: javascript, systemjs

Looking at the docs for [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) I can not find an example of loading multiple dependencies at the same time. I would expect an api something like...

```
System.import(['jquery.js','underscore.js']).then(function($, _) {
    // ready to go with both jQuery and Underscore...
});
```

I would expect it to use promises to load all dependencies in parallel, and execute the callback once all are complete. Is this possible? If not, is there a reason why this functionality is not implemented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible with Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([
    System.import('jquery'),
    System.import('underscore')
]).then(function(modules) {
    var jquery = modules[0];
    var underscore = modules[1];
});
```

But it is ugly as you can see. There is talk of considering allowing an array like your example at the spec level, but it would need to be in the module spec since this is a spec loader.

The better alternative really is to only have one entry point for an application, `app.js` and then have that load dependencies.

Comment: Even if you have just one entry point, how would you load multiple dependencies within app.js?

Comment: Late answer, but the AMD, CommonJS, and ES6 all have their own module import syntax that you can put in app.js to load everything your app needs. You should then be able to get away with only using System.import once to startup the app.

Comment: Unless you want to load modules conditionally. There is no way to use `import` syntax within a loop, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i would do it, take it carrefully: it's not tested.

```
var SystemImport = System.import;
System.import = function (name, options) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(name) !== '[object Array]')
        return SystemImport.apply(this, arguments);
    var self = this,
        imports = Promise.all(name.map(function (name) {
            return SystemImport.call(self, name); // should i pass options ?
        }));
    return {
        then: function (onfulfill, onreject) {
            return imports.then(function (dependencies) {
                return onfulfill.apply(null, dependencies);
            }, onreject);
        }
    };
};
```

This snippet will replace `System.import` with a wrapped version of itself allowing to use array of dependencies.

It returns a "thennable" object, this should work fine with any compliant promise implementation.

As the `.spread` method is not in the Promise A+ spec, this is the most spec compliant way I can think of...

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the shortest and DRYest way would be applying a `[].map()` to the `System.import` and then destructure its results:

```
Promise.all([
    'jquery',
    'underscore'
].map(url => System.import(url))).then(function ([$, _]) {
    // do stuff with results
});
```

Keep in mind that [Destructuring](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) still needs to be transpiled at the moment of writing this.

If you don't want to transpile you could write your own wrapper and spread script:

```
function spread(callback) {
    return function (args) {
        return callback.apply(undefined, args);
    }
}
function import(deps) {
    return Promise.all(deps.map(function (url) {return System.import(url);}));
}
```

and load it like:

```
import(['jquery', 'underscore']).then(spread(function ($, _) { /*...*/ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing.
I'm currently using Bluebird, Promise.all and Promise.spread to do this.
That's as "nice" as I could write it.

```js
Promise.all([
  SystemJS.import('jquery'),
  SystemJS.import('axios')
]).spread(function(jquery, axios){
  return jquery < axios;
});
```